# calculation of multiplicity of a subvariety

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, computer-algebra-systems

Suppose $I$ is a primary ideal and $J=\sqrt{I}$ , radical of it and $J$ now is a prime ideal. How can I use Macaulay2 to compute the multiplicity of $I$ along $J$.

When the scheme-theoretically image of $V(I)$ is just a point, I can use the function 'multiplicity' to compute it.

e.g.: R=QQ[x,y]; I=ideal(x^2,y^2);
Then I have multiplicty(I)=4 which is the multiplicity of $I$ along $(x,y)$.

Apparently, it doesn't work for higher dimension.

e.g.: R=QQ[x,y]; I=ideal(x^2-y);
It gives multiplicity(I)=2 but $I$ is already a prime ideal and we should expect the answer should be one.

Does anyone know how to find multiplicity when $V(\sqrt{I})$ has dimension higher than zero?

Comment: What is the definition of the multiplicity of $I$ along $J$?